# Jquery : Identify text change with out page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract the price from parent div class. It is working fine when initial page load. But I have a dropdown in my page. When I change the item, parent div price will be changed. But the extracted price is not changing. Because page is not refreshing.

```
var a = $('.price').text();
var t_section += '<p>Sign up to earn '+ rewardPts + ' points for this purchase</p>';
$('#msg').append(t_section );
```

How to find the price change?

I have tried `change(), trigger()` events. But, that is not working.

Comment: Can you please try adding watcher?

Comment: could you link the html as well ? the best way to do this would be the onchange handler of the dropdown

Comment: @TavishAggarwal, how to add watcher?

Comment: can you paste full code?

Comment: I have offered you the 2 skeletons. 1 specific and one far broader that should work for you. But without exact HTML provided you have to fit them into your code on your own. It should be easy enough.

Comment: @NNR Unless you post your full code I don't think anyone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `change()` function directly to the drop-down element? This is AFAIK most precise answer.

```
$('#yourDropdown').change(function () {
    var selection = this.value;
    // do something with the value
});
```

This is a far broader answer:
Generally, for most stuff, you can bind to `DOMSubtreeModified` - which is consistent and fires off on changes in the subtree of certain DOM node. If you bind it to the select element. When one option is selected it should fire.

```
$('#yourDropdown').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
  var selection = this.value;
  // handle the detected change
})
```

Problem is without exact HTML code where I can see exact classes and structure of dropdown (maybe is something non-standard?) it's hard to write the handle part. Also, when change is detected where is the value stored? A fiddle would be nice so I can edit in the parts you are missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my code, it might help you.

```js
$('#priceSelect').change(function() {
  var rewardPts = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  var t_section = '<p>Sign up to earn '+ rewardPts + ' points for this purchase</p>';
  $('#msg').append(t_section);
});
```

```html
<select name="price" id="priceSelect">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
</select>
  
<div id="msg"></div>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code for Your issue

**HTML CODE**

```
<select name="price" id="priceSelect">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
</select>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

**JS CODE HERE**

```
calcuateRewardPoint(); // Function Call initial pageLoading

$('body').on("change","select",function() {
  calcuateRewardPoint();
});

// Calculate RewardPoint

function calcuateRewardPoint(){
  var rewardPts = $("#priceSelect").find(":selected").val();
  var t_section = '<p>Sign up to earn '+ rewardPts + ' points for this purchase</p>';
  $('#msg').append(t_section);
}

[To see in jsFiddle][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#priceSelect").change(function(){
var  t_section = ('<p>Sign up to earn '+ $(this).val()+ ' points for this purchase</p>');
$("#msg").html(t_section)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="price" id="priceSelect">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
</select>

<div id="msg"></div>
```